# Subprocess.call and programs that ask for input

Tags: python, subprocess

So I'm writing a program that, at one point, has to call a separate executable. I'm using `subprocess.call` to have my python script call said executable from the command line. The problem is that, during its execution, that executable prompts the user for input twice. I want my script to give the executable that input, but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is on Windows 10, should that make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("exec_name arguments")
```

Pass the inputs as arguments to the executable.

Comment: The inputs are asked for in a prompt to the user during the execution of the executable. Extra arguments don't seem to do anything.

Comment: "The problem is that that executable prompts the user for input twice. I want my script to give the executable that input, but I'm not sure how to do it." I assumed you had the inputs beforehand and the executable's call for inputs was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [`subprocess.Popen` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to create an instance representing the subprocess with which you want to later communicate through the instance `.communicate()` method.

Something like this should work

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([executable_name] + args,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(input_str)
```

`subprocess.check_call` does something similar under the hood.

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me an error saying that it was looking for a bytes-type input and not a string. Switching the input to a byte array then gave me "Cannot send input after starting communication", which is rather confusing.